# How to override layout params of child layouts when including

Tags: android, xml

Let's say I have `my_custom_view.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/hello"
              android:padding="10dp" />

    ........
</LinearLayout>
```

And I want to include `my_custom_view` on my `activity_main.xml` multiple times.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <include layout="@layout/my_custom_view.xml"/>
    <include layout="@layout/my_custom_view.xml"/>
    <include layout="@layout/my_custom_view"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But what if I want just override text (textview) on each `my_custom_view` views.

i.e. How can I override a parameter of a child element of the parent `my_custom_view.xml` when used with `<include/>` tag?

I know I could create a custom view class with attributes, but I'd like my views to be rendered directly on Android Studios design view.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do complex logic like that in xml.

Custom views are rendered just like any other view (just rebuild the project after creating class). They also give you much more flexibility with attrs.xml as you are already aware